# PHP: Ok to store database handle in global variable?

Tags: php

i am creating a simple authentication, acl script. i wonder if its ok to store a PDO database handle in a global variable?

whats the bad effects of using a global variable? anyone can edit from anywhere?

if i create a singleton like in zend framework `Zend_Registry` how will it make things any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine. It will be destroyed when the request is over anyway so no other process will edit it or anything. Just make sure you use include_once so it doesn't connect every time.